# Why can't aggregate operations be performed on arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, aggregate

I cannot perform aggregate operations on arrays. Why can't aggregate operations be performed on arrays in C++?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: What are *"aggregate operations"*?

Comment: An Aggregate Operation is performed on a data structure as a whole as opposed to on an individual element

Comment: I am voting to close this since it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) is there for aggregate operations.

However, it was reportedly standardized before it was quite finished, and I've never seen code using it.